# Issue with absolute position on webflow

Tags: html, css, webflow

I'm trying to develop a website for my company on Webflow.

On the section shown in picture you can see a vertical navbar and 2 different contents (app screenshots and texts) according to the selection.

The right part works properly but I can't find a solution for the screen shot.

Actually, I made a Horizontal flex block including the phone, the navbar and the text.
The phone and the text are in extended mode, not the navbar.

For the effect of fusion between the navbar and the phone square I moved the navbar to the left and I worked with the shadow boxes.

Right now, the text change properly when the mouse is over a button.
When I set up the left part (square phone and the screenshots), the whole design breaks.

Can you help me please ??

Here the link to the webflow page :

https://preview.webflow.com/preview/ikinesis-test?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=ikinesis-test&preview=142bb9a901b87c8b6cf91e26da18a063&workflow=preview

[image: webflow interface]
[image: When the phone block is in absolute position]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say "the whole design breaks" are you referring to the point of about 1125px in screen width where your right column text starts overlapping? I've never worked with Webflow before but it looks like in the inspector it's using media queries and you may need to add one for that range so you can tweak the layout or trigger a different layout that you currently have sooner.

Comment: I edited the question with a screen when I set up the phone in absolute position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not a web-dev. In fact, I am a physical therapist xD. I have no idea what you were trying to tell me xD

Comment: That's okay. I'm just trying to understand your problem so I can troubleshoot it but unfortunately, it's hard to do that when working through a browser inspector instead of actual code. If I understand correctly, you want the buttons to be next to the phone but have the text section take up more horizontal space as you have it in the bottom screenshot?

Comment: I understand... I would like exactly what there is on the first screen shot. If I let the phone div in a relative position there isn't any design issue. When I set it in absolute, the buttons overlap the phone and the text is too large...

Comment: What screen size are you working at in your preview? If you want the information column to be taller you don't need to change the positioning of the phone, just change the `.paragraph-featurecontent` from `width: 100%;` to something smaller like `width: 60%`. You'll have to adjust the underlying contents as well.

Comment: I published a version with the absolute set up. 
I updated the post with different screenshots at different screen size

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out? Because I'm on your site now and it looks okay except that you need to adjust elements on your media queries on the tablet sizes because your text column starts to overflow and hide behind the background of another element.

Comment: Hi AStombaug, yes I just finished fixing it. I just come hidden for the devices other than the computer.

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to get it worked out! Sorry I couldn't be of much help :)

Comment: Thank you very much !! Actually, I started again from the beginning...

Comment: Sometimes starting over is the best solution LOL! Happy to do what little I could, best of luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Just updated the last modification. What do you think? https://ikinesis-test.webflow.io

Comment: Looks good! Didn't notice any issues at any sizes but make sure you test it on real devices too! :)